# Chef run_state - get list of directories in runtime and remove them

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe

I wish to get a list of directories under a certain path in runtime and remove all directories not in a list in my attributes file.

so if I have the following in my attributes:

```
default[:dir_list] = ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

and I have the following directory structure:

```
/path/to/dir/{a,b,c,d,e,f}
```

which is created at runtime by opening a tar file with {a,b,c,d,e,f} inside.

After the chef run I would like to have:

```
/path/to/dir/{a,b,c}
```

I have tried the following but it does not work:

```
ruby_block 'get list of directories to remove' do
  block do
    # get list of all dirs
    all_dirs = Dir.entries("/path/to/dir")
    # get list of all non-required dirs
    node.run_state["dirs_to_delete"] = all_dirs - node[:dir_list] - [".", ".."]
  end
end

node.run_state["dirs_to_delete"].each do | mydir |
  directory "/path/to/dir/#{mydir}" do
    recursive true
    action :delete
  end
end
```

The reason the above doesn't work is because

```
node.run_state["dirs_to_delete"].each do | dir |
```

is evaluated at compile time and is null.

Chef allows using "lazy {block}" but only inside a resource block and not in the external loop.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you looked at the [`zap` cookbook](https://supermarket.chef.io/cookbooks/zap)?

Answer (score 0):

Your attribute is returning nil value because ruby block has not run while loading your attribute in compile mode,I have modified the ruby block to run in compile mode and do nothing in converge mode.

```
ruby_block 'get list of directories to remove' do
  block do
    # get list of all dirs
    all_dirs = Dir.entries("/path/to/dir")
    # get list of all non-required dirs
    node.run_state["dirs_to_delete"] = all_dirs - node[:dir_list] - [".", 
    ".."]
    :nothing
  end
end.run_action(:run)

node.run_state["dirs_to_delete"].each do | mydir |
  directory "/path/to/dir/#{mydir}" do
    recursive true
    action :delete
end
end
```